# Backbone.js collection.create function doesn't return updated model with wait: true

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, laravel-4

In using Backbone.js with Laravel 4, I am inserting into the database using this.collection.create() with the wait: true option. It inserts into the database alright, but it doesn't update the model if wait: true is set. So if I try output the collection again, it's not updated even though trying a success callback function returned a value and the POST request comes back positive.

The app is a contact managing system.
This is my model for a contact:

```
App.Models.Contacts = Backbone.Model.extend({

});
```

This is my View for adding a contact

```
App.Views.AddContact = Backbone.View.extend({
el: '#addContact',
events: {
    'submit': 'addContact',
},
initialize: function() { // cache values
    this.first_name = $('#first_name');
    this.last_name = $('#last_name');
    this.email_address = $('#email_address');
    this.description = $('#description');
},
addContact: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.collection = this.collection.create({
        first_name: this.first_name.val(),
        last_name: this.last_name.val(),
        email_address: this.email_address.val(),
        description: this.description.val(),
    }, { wait: true });

},
});
```

And this is the collection:

```
App.Collections.Contacts = Backbone.Collection.extend({
model: App.Models.Contacts,
url: '/projects/gamesapp/public/contacts',
});
```

And this is the script on the page that puts all this into action:

```
<script>
    new App.Router;
    Backbone.history.start();

    App.contacts = new App.Collections.Contacts;
    App.contacts.fetch().then(function() {
        new App.Views.App({ collection: App.contacts });
    });
</script>
```

What can I do to get this working? I want create in the view to update the model locally as well, which it doesnt seem to.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not in the js or backbone code, it was in the Laravel code I wrote.

It seemed that the POST returned a positive response and all, but the problem was in my controller's store method, **you have to return the create() function from the store() function!!!**, to make it clear:

```
public function store()
{
    $input = Input::all();

    return Contact::create(array( // YOU HAVE TO RETURN SOMETHING
        'first_name' => $input['first_name'],
        'last_name' => $input['last_name'],
        'email_address' => $input['email_address'],
        'description' => $input['description'],
    ));

}
```

My problem was ocurring because I wasn't returning it, just calling the Contact::create() function... (Contact is the Laravel Model)